# How to install Apache (httpd-2.4.25.tar.gz) on Linux Mint Debian edition?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, apache-httpd

I am getting an error message on passing this line of code in the Terminal:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/username/Server
```

**Error message**:

```
configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required
and available from http://pcre.org/
```

[image: Error Message on passing the line of code mentioned above]

I followed the link mentioned in the error message to extract `PCRE-8.40.tar.gz` and `PCRE2-10.21.tar.gz` in `home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib`.

Then I renamed the extracted folder as **PCRE** and **PCRE2**. Yet I am getting the same error message. What am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the PCRE library available to your compiler (strictly speaking, to the build system, which is looking for an installed library, and the `pcre-config` tool somewhere on the path). The simplest way to do this, if you have `root` access on your system (or `sudo`), is to install `libpcre3-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

If you don't have `root`, you'll have to install PCRE somewhere, build it and install it, then add the resulting `bin` directory to your path.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks **GAD3R** for editing my question and making it look better :)
Thanks a lot **Stephen** for solving my problem :)

---

Here is what I did after reading Stephen's solution:

- Installed `pcre` in `home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/pcre`. Let me illustrate how to do that:

Let's assume we extracted `pcre-8.40.tar.gz` in `/home/username/downloads/pcre`. We can either **right-click** on the workspace of this folder and click **open terminal** else type this command on the terminal:

```
$ cd /home/username/downloads/pcre
```

Now, let's install `pcre` in `home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/pcre` (i.e., PATH where you want to install pcre).

**Command:**

```
$ ./configure home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/pcre

$ make

$ sudo make install
```

**NOTE:** You can install `pcre2` by following same procedure.

---

- Now, we are ready to install Apache httpd-2.4.25:

Let's assume we extracted httpd-2.4.25.tar.gz in `home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25` and want to install it in `home/username/local/server`.

**Command:**

```
$ cd home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25

$ ./configure --prefix= home/username/local/server --with-pcre=home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/pcre

$ make

$ sudo make install
```

That's it. :)

---

If you got any error with `apr` then download the tar files of `apr`, `apr-iconv` and `apr-util` from [apr.apache.org](https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi) . And, extract it in `home/username/xyz/httpd-2.4.25/srclib` (i.e., the PATH where you installed `httpd` -> `httpd-2.4.25/srclib`).